# Git clone with ssh works in Linux but not in Windows PowerShell

Tags: linux, git, powershell, ssh, clone

I have a repo at GitHub. When cloning it in Linux using ssh it works fine:

```
> git clone git@github.com:henrikppersson74/frokenjennnie.git                                                  
Cloning into 'frokenjennnie'...
Enter passphrase for key '/home/----/.ssh/id_rsa':
.
.
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/*
```

When doing the same thing in Windows PowerShell it doesn't work:

```
> git clone git@github.com:henrikppersson74/frokenjennnie.git
Cloning into 'frokenjennnie'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have copied my private and public SSH keys from Linux to my Windows machine and they are stored in my ~/.ssh/ as id_rsa and id_rsa.pub.
It seems to work when I try to access github.com with ssh from PowerShell:

```
> ssh git@github.com
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\-----/\.ssh\id_rsa':
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi henrikppersson74! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
Connection to github.com closed.
```

This is the same answer I get when doing this in Linux. I guess this means the my SSH-key par is ok?

When working in Eclipse in Windows, using the "Git Repositories" view it works fine to clone the same repo.

Previously I created new SSH keys in the PowerShell and copied the public one to GitHub, but with the same result.

My `~/.ssh/config` file lookes like this:

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    IdentityFile ~\.ssh\id_rsa
    User git
    ForwardAgent yes
```

I am using Git version:

```
> git --version
git version 2.28.0.windows.1
```

Unfortunately I get no extra information from using the --verbose flag:

```
> git clone git@github.com:henrikppersson74/frokenjennnie.git --verbose
Cloning into 'frokenjennnie'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

It doesn't help to add the key to the ssh-agent:

```
> ssh-add C:\Users\-----\.ssh\id_rsa
Enter passphrase for C:\Users\-----\.ssh\id_rsa:
Identity added: C:\Users\------\.ssh\id_rsa (C:\Users\-----\.ssh\id_rsa)
> git clone git@github.com:henrikppersson74/frokenjennnie.git --verbose
Cloning into 'frokenjennnie'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Could my old keys be cashed somewhere?

Does anyone have any idea about why I am not able to clone my repo in Windows PowerShell? I would be so grateful for some help.

Comment: The `git` command in PowerShell seems to use a different key file. Your private key copied from your Linux system needs a passphrase while the command in PowerShell seems to find a key that doesn't require a passphrase. What version(s) of Git did you install on your Windows system? Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments to answer.  I have tried to fix the formatting of your commands and output. I'm not sure if I correctly recognized what was meant for formatting. Please check if everything is correct and fix it if necessary. It's best to use copy&paste.

Comment: To add to @Bodo's helpful comment, try adding `--verbose` (that's 2 dashes) to your `git clone` statement in PowerShell, might reveal how and where it's finding the (wrong) key file

Comment: OMG, this is a bit embarrassing... Found the problem. A program I installed a while ago change my `%HOME%` environment variable. When I changed it back to `C:\Users\<userid>` it worked like charm. Thank you very much @Bodo and @Mathias R. Jessen for guiding me :-)!

Comment: @HenrikPPersson You can write the details how you debugged and fixed this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my `%HOME%` environment variable was set to the wrong location. When I changed it back to `C:\Users\<userid>` it worked like charm. Apparently SSH first looks for a key in `%HOME%\.ssh\`, then for en entry in `%HOME%\.ssh\config\` and last it uses the keys added to the `ssh-agent`.